# Sticky Footer Below ListView in Android Layout

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, sticky-footer

I want to put an ad layout at the bottom of a ListView.  I want it to stick to the bottom of the page and the listview almost scrolling going behind it.

This is what I have and it doesn't work:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:longClickable="true" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

It is that bottom LinearLayout I need to just stay at bottom.  And I want ListView to go all the way to the bottom. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Can you put the XML layout here?

Comment: sorry, not sure what happened.

Comment: So, what you want is a bottom bar, always visible at the bottom of the screen? (Is better if you put the whole file here so we can see the parent view too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change attributes of your `ListView` to :

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:longClickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

EDIT: Also check that parent layout of your piece of code is `LineareLayout` with attribute `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution of your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your answer is probably more valid because it uses Relative Layouts.  But I used the other guys answer because it more closely worked with what I was doing. thanks though.  I upvoted you.

Comment: Thanx KickingLettuce, i use this way when i want to use adview at bottom