# Footerview not displaying always when scrolling the listview

Tags: android, android-listview, footer

I have a listview with an adapter. I want to add a footer and that this footer will be displayed when scrolling the listview. Right now with this code the footerview is displayed when the listview is finished. In the onCreate method of the list i have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_imagenes_subidas_main);

    // load list application
    listImagenes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvImages);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer3buttons, listImagenes,
            false);
    listImagenes.addFooterView(footer, null, false);

    // create new adapter
    ImagenesAdapter adapter = new ImagenesAdapter(this, ListadoImagenes());
    // set adapter to list view
    listImagenes.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Could you please help me with this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If you want a footer view that is always on screen, you need to put that view in your layout below the `ListView`. If you want the footer to scroll with the list (so it appears as a list item after the last one in the adapter), use `addFooterView()`.

Comment: how do i do this? Is there an example?

Comment: An example of how to display a footer view always on screen when using listview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888574/sticky-footer-below-listview-in-android-layout

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly what you wan't is a "sticky" footer the `addFooterView` method add a footer after the last view item, for a sticky footer you have to roll your own, or use an external library for it.

Comment: how do i do this? Is there an example?

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Don't forget to call this method BEFORE you set the adapter.